# unable to assert_select in rails 4 test case

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, automated-tests

I have a string that contains html tag and some brackets. For example

```
mystr = "<h1>Hello(greeting message for A,B, and C). </h1>"
```

i want to assert that string with a p tag.

first i remove the tag using

```
tag_free_string =  ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(mystr)
```

than i apply Regex escape.

```
final_atr = Regexp.escape (tag_free_string)
```

and finally assert like this

```
assert_select 'p.alert', /#{final_atr}/
```

but getting error the string contains many \\ in it.

Comment: Perhaps, you have a typo: `<\h1>` should be `</h1>`. Try.

Comment: yes i have </h1> in code but miss typed in post